# DRF: Do not expost API

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I am using Django with Django Rest Framework. I have disabled the browseable api in the `settings.py` file, however, when I visit http://example.com/api - where example.com is my domain - I get this response:

```
{"api/projects":"http://example.com/api/projects/"}
```

I don't want it to print that, it shouldn't print anything. I didn't define that endpoint. How can I tell DRF not to expose any information about my API unless I specifically tell it to?

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your problem correctly please make sure to always include some (more) code for readers to comprehend your problem.

My Idea: Use the `SimpleRouter` to set up the URLs for the API, as the `DefaultRouter` is described as

> This router is similar to SimpleRouter as above, but additionally
>   includes a default API root view, that returns a response containing
>   hyperlinks to all the list views. It also generates routes for
>   optional .json style format suffixes.

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#defaultrouter

Is this what you were looking for?